Nvidia Isaac ROS Visual SLAM with OpenCV
Hey Robotics Community,
i successfully completed the Tutorial for Visual SLAM:
https://nvidia-isaac-ros.github.io/concepts/visual_slam/cuvslam/tutorial_isaac_sim.html
Now i want to show the colorful dots observation point clouds in a camera viewer (Link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNTi1osPSIA):

I managed to create a script with openCV which subscribe to the /visual_slam/vis/observations_cloud topic
:
https://streamable.com/5mtfnk
https://streamable.com/w769sz
However, it doesn’t match with the observation_cloud in rviz2.
Any ideas?
Thank you very much in advanced ;)
